# adding home directory after -M option

Tags: centos, useradd

First off I'm new to Linux. I have created a new user called "**ginny**" with `-M` option.

Now I'm trying to assign a home directory with `usermod -d /link/to/directory ginny` but it doesn't assign a home directory to user ginny.

```
% su - ginny returns an error
su: warning : cannot chance directory to /abc: No such file or directory
-bash-3.2$:
```

The `pwd` command returns `/root` for user ginny (maybe because i haven't created her a home directory) but is there any switch that can now allow me to assign a home directory to user ginny?

Comment: it is small `-m` , you can check `man useradd`

Comment: I think you do not have any data in your home direcory, if so then try fresh using following:
`#userdel -r ginny  

#mkdir /abc  

#useradd -m /abc ginny;passwd ginny   

#chown -R ginny:ginny /abc`

Comment: @RahulPatil User ginny is already existing ..........

Comment: you have to use `-m` at first time when you create user.. now you have to delete it and recreate it again using `useradd -m ginny -d /abc` no need to create `/abc` dir it will create it automatically with user ginny permission because of `-m`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user's home directory doesn't exist. `usermod` changes the home directory field in `/etc/passwd` but doesn't create the directory. You need to create it manually.

```
cp -a /etc/skel /link/to/directory          # or mkdir /link/to/directory to create an empty home directory
chown ginny:ginnygroup /link/to/directory   # where ginnygroup is ginny's primary group
chmod 755 /link/to/directory                # or 711 or 700 or 751 or 750 as desired
```